# What is this thinking type effect called?

Tags: film-techniques, naked-gun-final-insult

In *Naked Gun 33 1/3: The Final Insult (1994)*, Scene where Frank tries to take the
gun out of his pouch, but it was not there. Then he thinks past what
really happened to his gun. While thinking this effect used.

[image]

What is this effect called ?

Answer (score 6):

The effect itself is a **crossfade**

The purpose is to create a **flashback** so the audience know 'what he's thinking/what happened before'.

The 'wobbly flashback' is one of the most clichéd flashback devices - usually accompanied by a harp or piano playing an upward glissando or whole-tone scale - of course, perfectly suited to this type of movie, which is perfectly aware of the tiredness of the cliché.

See [TV Tropes - Flashback Effects](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/FlashbackEffects)